# Not able to deploy phonegap app on device when two devices are connected to the system

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to install a phonegap 3.3 app onto android devices. I have connected two devices to my system. 
-android 4.2 and android 2.3

```
adb devices
```

shows me both the devices, none 'offline'. Both are are usb debugging enabled. The android 4.2 device gives me an option to connect as media device or camera. The android 2.3 does not give any such option.

Individually i am able to run/install the app on either of the devices when only one of the devices is usb connected to the system at a time.

But when both the devices are usb connected it only deploys on the android 2.3 device. It totally ignores the android 4.2 device. I tried pointing to the device for installation as follows but it does not work

```
phonegap run android --device=410013f00
phonegap run android --device=012345DEF
```

it always deploys on the first device. Please let me know if and how it is possible to have the app deployed on the second device as well i.e. when both are usb connected. It is a pain to attach & remove the devices alternatively again and again for testing. Thanks!

Note: The device ids used above are only for representation and not the actual ids. Let me know if you need actual ids. Also if it is of any help the system that the devices connect to is actually a Windows VM

Comment: did you get those device ids from the output of **adb devices**?

Comment: @helleye yes i am using the same ids that i get out of the adb devices command [what you see in the question are just masked ids or few characters omitted. Let me know if you want me to paste full ids here]

Comment: Not sure am i understand correctly...If you are using eclipse then use run configurations in `target` tab select `always prompt to pick a device`

Comment: @Aravin I have been using phonegap command line. not so comfortable with eclipse currently. i use notepad++ for editing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with phonegap, but it should be easy to do it with adb.

```
adb -s DEVICE_ID install -r package_name.apk
```

You could put two lines of this command into a batch file and run it after build.